# Mellin transform between heat kernel and zeta-function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-operators, heat-equation

For some notion of a "positive operator" $D$ of "Laplacian type" one seems to be able to define a notion of a zeta-function as $\xi(s,f,D) = Tr_{L^2}(f D^{-s})$ where $f \in L^2$ (the space of square-integrable functions on the chosen manifold). Also one now defines the generalized heat-kernel corresponding to this as $K(t,f,D) = Tr_{L^2}(f\, exp(-tD))$.

Now I am faced with the following identity for which I would like to know the proof:

$$ \xi(s,f,D) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^{\infty} t^{s-1} K(t,f,D) \, dt $$

---

It would be helpful if someone could also elaborate on the notion of what is a "positive operator of Laplacian type" (..I have some rough idea based on specific examples..) and if someone could specify peculiarities in the above equations that are likely to come up if one goes to non-compact manifolds like hyperbolic spaces.

I am mostly interested in doing this on hyperbolic spaces.

Comment: Can we suppose that $D$ is self adjoint?

Comment: @shu Isn't the first equality in Liviu's answer the self-adjoint-ness?

Comment: yes, Liviu's answer is in the self-adjoint case. Such a result also exists for some non self-adjoint operator. But much more complicated.

Comment: Interesting question! What's the corresponding operator for the zeta function? Does it has a familiar name? I'd also like to see some applications.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Being of Laplacian type means that $D$ is a second order p.d.o. whose principal symbol coincides with that of a Laplacian of a metric $g$ on the manifold. Being positive signifies that   that for any  smooth functions with compact support  $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$ $f_0, f_1:  M\to \bR$, $f_0\neq 0$,   you have

$$ \int_M (Df_0)\cdot f_1 dV_g =\int_M f_0 \cdot (D f_1) dV_g,\;\; \int_M (Df_0) f_0 > 0. $$

In case the manifold $M$ is compact, $\dim M=m$, then $D$ has a  discrete spectrum

$$ 0<\lambda_0\leq \lambda_1\leq \cdots. $$

Let $(\Psi_k)_{k\geq 0}$ denote an orthonormal basis of $L^2(M)$ consisting of eigenfunctions, $D\Psi_k=\lambda_k\Psi_k$.

For $s>-m$, then  $fD^{-s}$ is an integral operator with integral kernel $\newcommand{\eK}{\mathscr{K}}$

$$ \eK_{f D^{-s}}(x,y) =\sum_{k\geq 0} \lambda_k^{-s} f(x)\Psi_k(x) \Psi_k(y), $$

while $fe^{-tD}$ is an integral operator with kernel

$$\eK_{fe^{-tD}}(x,y)= \sum_{k\geq 0} e^{-t\lambda_k} f(x)\Psi_k(x) \Psi_k(y). $$

Then

$$ \xi(s,f,d)=\int_M \eK_{fD^{-s}} (x,x) dV_g(x)=\sum_{k\geq 0} \lambda_k^{-s} \int_M f(x) |\Psi_k(x)^2| dV_g (x), $$

$$ K(t,f, D)=\int_M \eK_{fe^{-tD}} (x,x) dV_g(x)=\sum_{k\geq 0} e^{-\lambda_k t}  \int_M f(x) |\Psi_k(x)^2| dV_g (x). $$

Now use the  elementary identity

$$ \lambda^{-s}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^\infty t^{s-1} e^{-\lambda t} dt. $$

Comment: Nicolescu Thanks for your efforts. (1) I am not sure I find the last identity "elementary" ;P - I was infact stuck on that before I posted this question! (2) Can you comment on what happens on hyperbolic manifolds? Anything (what if?) changes in the argument of yours?

Comment: @Anirbit, Last identity is almost the definition of Gamma function by changing the variable $t\to \lambda t$.

Comment: On noncompact manifolds  there is a first issue  namely  the selfadjointness of $D$. If $M$ is a complete manifold, and $D$ is the usual Laplacian,  then it has a unique selfadjoint extension to $L^2$.  For complete hyperbolic manifolds  check this paper  and the references therein. http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/JEDP/JEDP_1987___/JEDP_1987____A17_0/JEDP_1987____A17_0.pdf

Comment: @Liviu Thanks for the reference! Will read that. On a related note I was wondering if this integral representation of the generalized zeta-function related to these kinds of identities like, $\xi(3) = \frac{8\pi^3}{3}\int_0^{\infty}d\lambda \frac{\sqrt{\lambda}}{1+e^{2\pi\sqrt{\lambda}}}$ - could you kindly shed some light?

Comment: That integral description of zeta is not that subtle.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu Can you give a reference to these kind of representations also? So you are saying that these two kinds of integral representations of the zeta function are unrelated?